# What do you call a fundamental question long time not-answered on a scientific basis?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

I mean such general questions as

- How did the Universe form?
- How will it evolve?
- How did the life origin?
- etc.

These have been mind-boggling questions, that are only now gathering enough observational ground to be scientifically-answerable. And what do you call that? (an adjective or even better a noun)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question that has not yet been answered is usually called an *open question*, an *open problem*, or an *unsolved question*.  These do not necessarily refer to fundamental scientific issues - you could use them to describe any problem or question without a known solution - but you can use them for scientific questions.

Examples and references:

[Open problem, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_problem)

["Welcome to the Open Problem Garden, a collection of unsolved problems in mathematics."](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/)

[Republican debate leaves Trump an open question](http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/d4f35762-3d1d-11e5-8613-07d16aad2152.html#slide0)